# Android: Static variable retrieved from BroadcastReceiver different from same variable retrieved in MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, oop

I am writing a basic Android alarm application. In `MainActivity`, I set the volume to 25 and printing the volume in `MainActivity` shows 25 (correct :D). However, when I print the volume in the `BroadcastReceiver`, which launches 10 seconds latter, the result is 0. This seems strange, considering that the variable is public and static, and is in a public class in the same directory as `MainActivity` and `BroadcastReceiver`, which means that it should be shared by both the `MainActivity` and the `BroadcastReceiver`.

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.basicalarmsetter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    final static int RQS_1 = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        UserSettings.volume = 25;
        System.out.println("UserSettings.volume (MainActivity) = " + UserSettings.volume);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Trigger an alarm 10 seconds after launch
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this, RQS_1, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

**AlarmReceiver.java**:

package com.example.basicalarmsetter;

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context k1, Intent k2) {
        System.out.println("UserSettings.volume (AlarmReceiver) = " + UserSettings.volume);
    }
}
```

**UserSettings.java**:

```
package com.example.basicalarmsetter;

public class UserSettings {
    public static int volume = 0;
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.basicalarmsetter">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
            <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:process=":remote" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Results from print statements**:

```
UserSettings.volume (MainActivity) = 25
UserSettings.volume (AlarmReceiver) = 0
```

Comment: First of all remove this line  `android:process=":remote"` from `receiver` and try to re-run program

Comment: can you post UserSettings class?

Comment: @NitinPrakash Posted the UserSettings :D

Comment: Are you killing your app after starting the alarm?

Comment: @NitinPrakash I definitely did not kill my app after starting the alarm :D

Answer (score 0):

Removing `android:process=":remote"` from my receiver specification in `AndroidManifest.xml` resolved the issue. Specifying the process as remote for a receiver runs it on a separate process, which means it does not access the same resources as the main process.